# Segmentation fault While reading from file and storing in vectors

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault

I have a file that contains value as following

```
33829731.00 -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00
```

I am using vector to store this values.

```
std::vector<double> V;
double value;
ifstream input("file.txt");
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    input >> value;
    V.push_back(value);
}
```

While I'm running this piece of code I'm getting following error,

```
3.38297e+07
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why is there a segmentation error here?

Comment: What're `cols`, `input`, and `value`?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: cols.size() is 15, that is the number of columns in the file.
input is the ifstream to read from the file
value is a double type variable.

I'm using g++ to compile

Comment: Okay.  I'm guessing `value` is a double and `input` is your file?  ...Actually, it would probably be more useful if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that others can replicate the problem.

Comment: I can't replicate the error.  Do you get the error while outputting data from the vector?  If so, what code are you using to output it?

Comment: No, I just put a `cout << value` after `input >> value` line to check if its correctly getting the values form the file. That's how I'm getting segmentation fault

Comment: Strange.  Could you edit the entire function into your question?  I still can't get it to segfault with that code as is.

Comment: Fixed it. The problem wasn't in this piece of code. I was using a two dimensional vector and didn't initialize the size. That's why it was giving me segmentation error. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: That's good, glad you found the problem.  You're welcome, although I don't really feel like I did anything you need to thank me for.